# Searchview in android Toolbar

Tags: android, android-actionbar, android-toolbar, searchview

I am trying to build a searchview in the toolbar ion my android app, but am getting a null pointer exception in the 3rd line of onCreateoptionsMenu method. Any help will be appreciated, thank you  in advance.

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {

    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    SearchManager searchManager =(SearchManager) getSystemService(Context.SEARCH_SERVICE);
    SearchView searchView =(SearchView) menu.findItem(R.id.search).getActionView();
    searchView.setSearchableInfo(searchManager.getSearchableInfo(getComponentName()));
    return true;

}
```

Here is my menu.xml -

```
<item
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_search"
    android:id="@+id/action_search"
    android:orderInCategory="200"
    android:title="Search"
    app:showAsAction="ifRoom" />
```

Comment: please upload R.menu.main file too.

Comment: Can you attach your logcat?

Comment: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">
    <item
        android:id="@+id/action_search"
        android:orderInCategory="200"
        android:title="Search"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_search"
        app:showAsAction="ifRoom" />
</menu>

Comment: id is wrong in xml it is **action_search** and YOu are using **search** as id.

Comment: getting null point exception in line after changing to searchView.setSearchableInfo(searchManager.getSearchableInfo(getComponentName()));

Answer (score 0):

Try changing this line:

```
SearchView searchView = (SearchView) menu.findItem(R.id.action_search).getActionView();
```

Comment: getting null point exception in line after changing to searchView.setSearchableInfo(searchManager.getSearchableInfo‌​(getComponentName())‌​);

Comment: please add your logcat

Comment: E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                Process: worklist.com.worklist, PID: 3720                 java.lang.NullPointerException at worklist.com.worklist.MainActivity.onCreateOptionsMenu(MainActivity.java:201) at android.app.Activity.onCreatePanelMenu(Activity.java:2698)
                                                                         at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onCreatePanelMenu(FragmentActivity.java:362)at android.support.v7.view.WindowCallbackWrapper.onCreatePanelMenu(WindowCallbackWrapper.java

Comment: Please your MainActivity 201 no line add

Comment: this is line 201: SearchView searchView =(SearchView) menu.findItem(R.id.search).getActionView();

Comment: add your MainActivity

Answer (score 0):

Set SearchView class in menu.

```
   <item
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_search"
        android:id="@+id/action_search"
        android:orderInCategory="200"
        android:title="Search"
        app:actionViewClass="android.support.v7.widget.SearchView"
        app:showAsAction="ifRoom" />
```

Comment: i have options_menu.xml in menu folder, but getting the same error:    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">
    <item android:id="@+id/search"
        android:title="@string/search_title"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_search"
        app:showAsAction="ifRoom"
        android:actionViewClass="android.widget.SearchView" />
</menu>

Answer (score 0):

You missd  `app:actionViewClass="android.support.v7.widget.SearchView"` attribute.
 And you need to import `android.support.v7.widget.SearchView;`

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">
        <item
            android:id="@+id/action_search"
            android:icon="@drawable/search"
            android:title="@string/Search"
            app:actionViewClass="android.support.v7.widget.SearchView"
            app:showAsAction="always|collapseActionView" />
    </menu>
```

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to add `actionViewClass` in menu.xml

Add these line to you `menu.xml`

```
...
app:showAsAction="always|collapseActionView"
android:actionViewClass="android.support.v7.widget.SearchView" />
```

While in your Java code find `SearchView` using -

```
SearchView searchView = (SearchView) MenuItemCompat.getActionView(menu.findItem(R.id.action_search));
```

Reference - [MenuItemCompat](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/view/MenuItemCompat.html#getActionView(android.view.MenuItem))

Answer (score 0):

Try to use this

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
    // Inflate menu to add items to action bar if it is present.
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
    // Associate searchable configuration with the SearchView
    SearchManager searchManager =
            (SearchManager) getSystemService(Context.SEARCH_SERVICE);
    SearchView searchView =
            (SearchView) menu.findItem(R.id.menu_search).getActionView();
    searchView.setSearchableInfo(
            searchManager.getSearchableInfo(getComponentName()));

    return true;
}


<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:appcompat="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/tools">

<item
    android:id="@+id/action_settings"
    android:title="@string/action_settings"
    android:orderInCategory="100"
    app:showAsAction="never"/>

<item
    android:id="@+id/menu_search"
    android:title="@string/menu_search"
    appcompat:actionViewClass="android.support.v7.widget.SearchView"
    appcompat:showAsAction="always"/>
```

Comment: please can u provide me a link where i can finf an example of how to implement a searchview in a toolbar..